# How to reload tomcat after deploying the war from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, tomcat8

When I make any changes in properties file of the java application and committed to source code repository(SVN),After deploying the application to tomcat using jenkins those changes are not reflecting until restarting the tomcat.So I added a script to reload the tomcat in post build task of jenkins.

**wget http://xyz:pwd@ipaddress:port/manager/text/reload?path=/**

It is reloading the tomcat after build success.But I need it to be done after deployment.because changes are moved to tomcat after deployment.Any help would be appreciated.

or else is there any other alternative to do this?